# how to understand pointer to an array with a syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
//A structure to describe a matrix.
typedef struct matrix{
  int x, y, size, original_size, *data;
};
//Function to index matrices. 
int get(matrix m, int x, int y)
{
  return m.data[m.original_size * (m.x + x) + m.y + y];
}
```

I'm attempting to understand the line m.original_size * (m.x + x) + m.y + y in this C code. I need more elaboration on this line, m.data[m.original_size * (m.x + x) + m.y + y].

My attempt: Data is a pointer, which points to the address of array m.data. But then I get confuse trying to understand the rest of the statement. Especially * (m.x + x) + m.y + y.

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand. Everything inside the `[]` is basic integer arithmetic used to calculate an array index. So are you saying you don't understand integer operations? Or you don't understand **why** the code is doing that. If it is the latter we cannot help you with just the code you have shown. Because the answer to that depends on how `data` is allocated and used in the rest of the program.

Comment: It's a two-dimensional array implemented using one-dimensional array. The expression `* (mx. + x)` calculates for the position of the row while `m.y + y` calculates for the column in that row. Had it been a two-dimensional array, it would be something like `m.data[m.x + x][m.y + y]`.

Comment: @alvits array and pointer are not the same.  You can use the same syntax to access each, but they are different

Comment: @alvits: `m.data + m.original_size * (m.x + x) + m.y + y).` should be `*(m.data + m.original_size * (m.x + x) + m.y + y))` to evaluate to the same as `m.data[m.original_size * (m.x + x) + m.y + y]` evaluates to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is designed to represent a matrix (which is stored in `*data`) and a sub matrix, which is defined as starting at the m.x-th row and the m.y-th column. Hence, the `get()` function is really to access data in sub matrix, and the x & y indices are transformed to their positions in the original full matrix.

Comment: in other words, are you saying the m.x and m.y is the starting point? so m.x+x iterator to x? I'm kind of confuse on (m.original_size*).

Comment: `m.original_size` is the width of the original matrix. Rather than be stored in 2D, the matrix is stored row by row in 1D. Hence, to find the element at (x,y) the corresponding array element would be `m.data[x*m.original_width + y]`.

Comment: This function only differs slightly because it is interested in a smaller sub matrix (as stated above). Why that is the case is not clear from the code you have posted, but presumably it is useful for whatever algorithm this is being used in.